# Stackoverflow comment highlight when id of comment is hit in url

Tags: html, dom, anchor

I have seen when ever we enter a url in browser, metioned below, the comment is hightlighted.
ie. comment element gets a background color.

[Chrome does not display images on Refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183966/chrome-does-not-display-images-on-refresh#comment23177053_16190764)

Any one know, how do we achieve this, background color for that element, where id element is trigger from url
.. or
is there any DOM Level parameter where we can call javascript function

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you clarify?

Comment: What's the question here? Am I the only one who is not getting this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be implemented using JS:

1. Retrieve `location.hash` on page load.
2. Find `a` tag with the same hash (assuming every comment has an unique hash).
3. Find the corresponding comment container and perform an animation.

Answer (score 4):

You can get hash on document.ready or document.load then do what you want,

Here is an example with [mootools highlight function](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Fx/Fx.Tween#Element%3ahighlight).

```
window.addEvent('load', function () {
    var id = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    if (id != "")
        $(id).highlight("#ccc");
});
```

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/wUF5e/2/show/light/#comment)

[CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/wUF5e/2/)